# Solutions for out of band biometric login

Tags: authentication, biometrics, fido

I am enhancing our login flow to include biometric verification via your phone. The user will log in to the desktop app but will have to verify their identity via their phone. We already have an app and want to now accept login verification requests.

I have things "working" as a PoC. However, I am unsure if our solution will leave us vulnerable or if I am missing to ensure better security around an out of band authentication.

At a high level this is what I am doing

**Pairing stage:**

- User will register and be required to scan a QRCode
- The QRCode has a UUID attached (and some other properties)
- When we scan the qrcode from the device we send a JWT containing the device token and UUID to an endpoint
- We store the device token with their username in the DB

**Authentication stage:**

- The user enters their username
- We generate a UUID and start the verification flow
- Since we have their device token we send a push notification via the apn provider which also includes the UUID
- We poll our store for the UUID
- The user sees the notification on their phone and is asked to approve
- FaceID or TouchId is requested
- Once successful we make an API call back to our auth service which stores the UUID along with a success message
- The polling sees this success and establishes a session

Are there any solutions out there we should be using? I know there is FIDO for the biometrics. There is also [Ping Identity](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingid/page/uij1580998449635.html) Or does my solution seem like it will be work well and maintain a high level of security?

I am also thinking of replacing JWT communication from phone to our auth service with a mutual TLS. i.e the phone has a certificate and so does out service. I'm not the biggest fan of JWT and mTLS seems like a good solution to ensure tighter security for our endpoint.

Any feedback is appreciated

Comment: You can use OIDC device authorization flow together with biometric authentication in device which will be used by your OIDC provider to authenticate the user.

Comment: Interesting @defalt Would that be used for registering? I would like a push notification to the phone so the end user can accept or deny the request to login. Can I use OIDC device authorization flow for both registering then verifying by push?

Comment: Is the user registering initially on PC or mobile? If on PC, where does your mobile get the JWT key from? Actually, what is the point of the JWT at all, if *any* client has the key? Are you in any way enforcing the use of biometrics or is this just a matter of "some client has to call the API with this token, and the legit app won't do that without checking biometrics first"? Also, what if the user hasn't configured biometrics and just uses PIN? Finally, UUIDs are *UNIQUE*, not *SECURE*; a v4 (in particular) UUID should be secure but better to get 128 bits of entropy from a CSPRNG directly.

Comment: They will be registering on PC @CBHacking. Perhaps JWT is not needed actually. The important thing is that during pairing I get the device token so I can send push notifications to the user for subsequent logins. I wanna avoid reinventing the wheel but need a secure connection from our auth service to the device to get the token and then send requests to the phone

Comment: I checked OIDC CIBA and it's best suited to your use case. OIDC CIBA does specify that the IdP sends approval request to the user.

Comment: Yeh I think it might work. Although I don't quite get how the device sends a success message back to the auth service. Like how does it bind the session?

Comment: [CIBA, explained by an implementer](https://darutk.medium.com/ciba-a-new-authentication-authorization-technology-in-2019-explained-by-an-implementer-d1e0ac1311b4)